# Libraries module. Where to extract?

Tags: theming

Where should I be extracting the [Libraries](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module, sites/all/modules or sites/all/libraries?

Answer (score 4):

As all the modules, it goes in site/all/modules, or in $config/modules, where $config is the directory containing the settings.php file currently used for the site. (See [drupal_system_listing()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_system_listing/7) to understand where Drupal looks for modules.)

sites/all/libraries is the directory where the third-party library files should go. (Although, that is not the only directory where the Libraries module looks for them.)

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside *site/all/modules*.

Also, there's no need to create a new *libraries* folder in *site/all/libraries*.

Comment: Actually, there is a reason for creating a "libraries" directory in sites/all/libraries. See [libraries_get_libraries()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21libraries%21libraries.module/function/libraries_get_libraries/7).